# Tearing package animation

Tags: animation, normals

I need to make animated opening of a [package]:

[image]

I need to completely remove an upper part of the package. The only way that I found is to separate upper part and animate it via bones:

[image]

BUT there is a visible [seam] between two parts which is impossible to hide for me:
[image]

Is there any way to make the seam invisible or animate it in the other way.

Many thanks. Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Custom Split Normals* to adjust your shading. The easiest way to set the normals would be to just save them before the split, and then split:

[image]

You could also make a copy of your object, <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> *Merge By Distance*, then use a *Data Transfer* modifier:

[image]

It will create *Custom Split Normals Data* automatically if not present. Probably you need to apply that modifier.

Geometry Nodes could be used too to save modified normals to an attribute and use this attribute in the shader…

Comment: Hi Markus, thanks for your reply. I've tryed the fisrt and the second methods and nothing changed. The third method I didn't try. Because don't understand how to do it as a beginner in geometry nodes.

Comment: Tryed again and it seems that the first method works.